# Django Channels. How to avoid the exception RuntimeError: Task got Future attached to a different loop?

Tags: python, django, websocket, redis, django-channels

I use `Django Channels` with `channel_layers` (`RedisChannelLayer`).
Using Channels I only need to get live messages from signals when post_save event happens.
I try to send a message from the `signals.py` module.
The fact that the first message is sending properly, I got it successfully in the js console,
but then **disconnection** from the socket happens **with an Exception**:
`RuntimeError: Task got Future attached to a different loop.`
It refers to *`...redis/asyncio/connection.py:831`*
All my settings were done properly in accordance with the documentation.
My project also uses `DRF`, `Celery`(on Redis), `Redis` itself, `Daphne` server.
I only try to implement it with Debug=True mode, let alone production.
I have no idea what happens and how to solve it.
Here are snippets from my code:

```py
    #consumers.py

    class LikeConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = "likes"
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()
    
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'type': 'chat',
            'message': message
        }))
```

---

```py
    #signals.py
    
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    
    @receiver(post_save, sender=Like)
    def new_like(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            'likes',
            {
                "type": "chat_message", 
                "message": "1212341324, 213413252345"
            }
        )
```

---

```js
    //script.js
    
    const likeSocket = new WebSocket(url);
    likeSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
      let data = JSON.parse(e.data);
      console.log(data);
    };
```

Comment: I try to move my signal receiver directly to the Consumer (@staticmethod decorated ) but to no avail. The almost same error occurs RuntimeError('Event loop is closed').

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of investigating the issue, I have realized the Exception, RuntimeError, in that case, is just a **Warning**, not Error.
Because the `server doesn't break and the Socket is going on` further.
And that "Warning" is still in a [Bug stage](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/859) in Channels developers.
It looks not beauty in the server console, but it works properly.
I **tried to try-except it**, but can't figure it out - don't understand what code invokes the Error to try-except it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, everything working perfectly but getting this "error" . Did you figure it out?

Comment: No. Seems that DjangoChannels bag.. just pollutes the console..((